# Handel namespace defined between two tags inside body - xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

The xml :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
  <GetDataResponse xmlns="http://example.com/webservices/">
     <GetDataResult>
        <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-abc-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-abc-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
           <CompListData xmlns="">
              <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                 <Comp>JL-C</Comp>
                 <Type>JOB</Type>
                 <Cost>Lakhs</Cost>
              </Table>
              <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
                 <Comp>JL-C1</Comp>
                 <Type>JOB1</Type>
                 <Cost>Lakhs</Cost>
              </Table>
           </CompListData>
       </diffgr:diffgram>
     </GetDataResult>
  </GetDataResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The xslt :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
exclude-result-prefixes="s xsi xsd ">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"></xsl:output>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:if test="s:Envelope/s:Body/GetDataResponse/GetDataResult/diffgr/CompListData/TableTable[@id='Table1']/Type">
        <JobType1>
            <xsl:value-of
                select="s:Envelope/s:Body/GetDataResponse/GetDataResult/diffgr/CompListData/TableTable[@id='Table1']/Type"></xsl:value-of>
        </JobType1>
    </xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="s:Envelope/s:Body/GetDataResponse/GetDataResult/diffgr/CompListData/TableTable[@id='Table2']/Type">
        <JobType2>
            <xsl:value-of
                select="s:Envelope/s:Body/GetDataResponse/GetDataResult/diffgr/CompListData/TableTable[@id='Table2']/Type"></xsl:value-of>
        </JobType2>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The Output i m getting is the first line of the xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

Can someone guide me how to handle the 'diffgr:diffgram' inside the body and get the value of 'Type' in the 'JobType' tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XPath expression has several flaws - mainly, ignoring the namespaces of the `GetDataResponse`, `GetDataResult`and `diffgram` elements, as well as that of the `id` attribute.

You also wrote `diffgr` instead of `diffgram`, and `TableTable` instead of `Table`.

Try instead:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:w="http://example.com/webservices/"
xmlns:d="urn:schemas-abc-com:xml-diffgram-v1"
exclude-result-prefixes="s w d">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="jobtype1" select="s:Envelope/s:Body/w:GetDataResponse/w:GetDataResult/d:diffgram/CompListData/Table[@d:id='Table1']/Type" />
    <xsl:variable name="jobtype2" select="s:Envelope/s:Body/w:GetDataResponse/w:GetDataResult/d:diffgram/CompListData/Table[@d:id='Table2']/Type" />
    <xsl:if test="$jobtype1">
        <JobType1>
            <xsl:value-of select="$jobtype1"/>
        </JobType1>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="$jobtype2">
        <JobType2>
            <xsl:value-of select="$jobtype2"/>
        </JobType2>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Not that the result produced here is not a well-formed XML document (no single root element).

Comment: - thanks for the soln, surely quite a lot a lot of mistakes, new at handling namespaces